# How to print out doubly linked list (ADT que)?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, adt, doubly-linked-list

I am making and ADT que, wanted to as you guys how to print out all the que.
This is my structs:

```
typedef int kintyr;

typedef struct qElem {
    struct qElem *prv;          
    kintyr *dat;                    

}qElem;

   typedef struct que {
    qElem *fr,*bk;              
    int cnt;                    
}que;
```

I put elements to the que, but when i want to print out them to the screen I get some kind of memory error:

```
void show(que *q)
{

do
    {
            printf( "%d\n", temp->bk->dat );
              q->fr = q->fr->prv;
            q->cnt--;
    }
    while (q->cnt != 0);

}
```

I only get one element and then program crashes. Any solutions?

Comment: Please give us a [SSCCE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your insert code could be faulty so need to verify that. Given the info, your `show()` code is also not correct. You are modifying the `Q` pointer in `q->fr = q->fr->prv` thus modifying queue contents. Also you should not decrease the queue size `q->cnt--`; that should be done while deleting nodes.

---

```
void show(que *q)
{
    qElem *ptr = q->fr;
    while (ptr != NULL) { /*assuming that last node's fr pointer is NULL*/
        printf("%d\n, *(ptr->dat)");
        ptr = ptr->fr; /*going forward*/
    }
}
```